# A library for printing internationalized, human-style time periods (with rounding)?

Tags: java, datetime, internationalization

Is there a library for printing time periods in the way people speak? I mean, it should convert the period given in exact time units to a "spoken" period with certain degree of inexactness, like:

- 360 days -> "1 year",
- 32 days -> "1 month",
- 385 days -> 1 year 1 month"

JodaTime approaches this by cutting off all the "zero" duration parts, but still it can't even turn days into months:

```
    PeriodFormatterBuilder builder = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().
        appendYears().appendSuffix(" year(s) ").
        appendMonths().appendSuffix(" month(s) ").
        appendDays().appendSuffix(" day(s)");


    MutablePeriod almostOneYear = new MutablePeriod(0, 0, 0, 360, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    StringBuffer durationInWords = new StringBuffer();
    builder.toPrinter().printTo(durationInWords, almostOneYear, Locale.ENGLISH);

    System.out.println(durationInWords.toString());
```

yields "360 days", not even "n months m days" (n,m — depending on what is a "standard" year). Maybe I'm using it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think there a library for that. Why not just create a simple function to do it for you, like:

```
  public static String toHumanFormat(int totalDays){
    int years = totalDays / 356;
    int months = (totalDays % 356) / 30;
    int days = totalDays % 356 % 30;
    return MessageFormat.format("{0,choice,0#|1#1 year|1<{0} years} " +
            "{1,choice,0#|1#1 month|1<{1} months} " +
            "{2,choice,0#|1#1 day|1<{2} days}",
            years, months, days).trim();
  }
```